# JS - Identifying initial cookie creation and any modifications

Tags: javascript, string, cookies, google-tag-manager

Through GTM i am trying to do the following:

Return '1' on the initial load of a cookie for user (var x = {{cookieValue}};) -where {{cookieValue}} is a GTM 1st party cookie variable.

Return '2' if cookie string value is !== to the string value of the cookie on the previous page.

For example, on the initial page load cookie 'x' has the value 'abcdef'. I want to return '1' since thats the initial creation of the cookie.

On the second page load, cookie 'x' has the string value 'abcdef'. I don't want to return anything.

The third page load, 'x' still has the same value. I don't want to return anything.

On the fourth page load, 'x' now has the string value 'abcdfe'. I want to return '2'.

On the fifth page loads. 'x' persists with the value 'abcdfe'. Return nothing.

Sixth page load. 'x' now has the value string 'acbdfe'. I want to return '2' again.

How can I achieve this through JS in GTM?

Thanks

Comment: GTM has no persistent memory. You would need to create a second cookie (or use local storage, or another alternative) populated by GTM to compare against.

Comment: Thanks. Say if I use locaStorage in a custom JS variable. eg   
if (window['Storage']) {

  localStorage.setItem('cookieValue', {{x}}); 

} else {

  {{x}}('cookieValue', 'true');
} 

where x is the value of the cookie. Will localStorage not capture the value of the cookie each time the page loads?

Comment: You compare the value in localstorage against the cookie, and update only when necessary.